# Does Android (> v. 4.0) support Bluetooth pairing with OOB association model (with NFC)?

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc

I would like to use NFC for OOB Bluetooth pairing. If an application uses an NDEF record with type name "application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob", does Android use OOB association model as described in the BT spec? Does a recent version of Android (> 4.0) expose an API to do this? If the answer is no, does Android use "Just Works" association model with connection over an insecure BT socket (unauthenticated link key)? I have seen an old post here that discusses this in the context of Android 3.2, but nothing more recent.

Comment: OOB bluetooth pairing over NFC works well for me - on the Windows 7 side I use [Stollmann SDK](http://www.stollmann.de/en/software/nfc/nfc-for-windows.html), on Android 5 everything is handled by OS once an NDEF message with `application/vnd.bluetooth.ep.oob` is received